# Calling server API and sending response to WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to make an API request from my watch app using `openParenApplication` and `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`.

The API call from `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` would get data from the server and send that data to WatchKit app as a reply.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What API?  How are you currently calling it from your app?

Comment: Thanks for replying!
REST API call.
Currently calling async API call from iPhone app to get data from server. Now want to send the updated data to apple watch kit app during communicating watch kit app to iPhone app.

Answer (score 1):

In your Watch:

```
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{@«request» : «myRequest» } reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // Parse your result here                
            }
            else {
                // Manage Error
            }
        }];
```

In app delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
    if ([userInfo["request"] isEqualToString:"myRequest"]) {
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userInfo[@«request »]]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (imageData) {
                    reply(@{«result» : imageData});
                }
                else {
                    reply(@{«error» : @"error"});
                }
            });
        });
    }else {reply(@{}); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a background task in your `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` method (check here for some advice: http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/11/one-weird-trick-to-fix-openparentapplicationreply), then simply call `reply()` in the your API call's completion block (or similar) and pass the results.